# How to run with t3 service in WebLogic in order to work with WLST

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

When started my WLST (Weblogic Scripting Tool) after setting JAVA_HOME, I am able to get into WLST, but as part my startup work I tried `connect()` command which in turn needs t3 protocol binding for the weblogic server which I try with WLST.

```
C:\bea\bea_12.1.2\wlserver\common\bin>wlst
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option UseSpinning; support was rem
oved in 7.0_40

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

wls:/offline> connect()
Please enter your username :system
Please enter your password :
Please enter your server URL [t3://localhost:7001] :
Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid system ...
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 19, in connect
  File "<iostream>", line 520, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Error getting the initi
al context. There is no server running at t3://localhost:7001
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
wls:/offline> connect()
Please enter your username :system
Please enter your password :
Please enter your server URL [t3://localhost:7001] :
```

How I can run t3 service for my weblogic instance.

Comment: By creating http `tunnel` & creating t3 `channel` for that http defaulted port for the weblogic instance through `Weblogic Admin Console`, we could connect WLST to the instance and do stuffs, my answer will be followed shortly.

Comment: So the WLST command becomes like this to not to be offline and to get things averted. `connect('system','w3bl0g1c,''http://localhost:62600')`. Port will be your instance port. So instead of `t3` `http` becomes wise through `tunnel`

Comment: Check this link for configuration. Accept all defaults for `channel` configuration. http://www.munzandmore.com/2015/ora/http-instead-t3-weblogic-wlst

Comment: you should have AdminServer up and running to connect via t3

Comment: This I had tried in my local system. I didn't had any managed instance of WebLogic. I had only AdminServer was running on 62600, but weren't able to connect WLST via t3. Do I need enable something in order to enable `t3` file protocol.

Comment: it says 'There is no server running at t3://localhost:7001' you should connect with 62600 then

Comment: lok at AdminServer.log. It must state that the server is running and listening on a port for t3 protocol. It'll be around "server running" line