# Is WLST is stateful

Tags: python, wlst

I had logged in once using python script (connect statement) as described in this Q&A Topic

[How to run with t3 service in WebLogic in order to work with WLST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328597/how-to-run-with-t3-service-in-weblogic-in-order-to-work-with-wlst)

And I had observed WLST (Weblogic Scripting Tool) is stateful and as part of next `wlst.cmd` execution in my Windows environment, it retains the connect statement of python program and maintains state,- instead of offline mode now it had come in connected mode to my local Weblogic Console. And I had shut my windows machine once.

I would like to know upto what extent it is stateful as there are commands like `activate()`, `save()` and so. And connecting to specific managed instance and all.

Answer (score 0):

`disconnect()` makes WLST to go offline, meaning it might wipe-out stored states.

Comment: disconnect() is not removing last connect state cache for a WebLogic Server. When WLST is initated I could see it is not coming offline state however it is disconnected all at once.

Comment: And just because WLST is statful, it doesn't retains each & every state, however retain certain levels of state from last session. So `cmo` Current Management Object has some implication of usage while directly operate through WLST. Rather it is good option to execute by a program say,- `__some_program__.py`